# Extending guideContainer in AEM to work with Adaptive Forms?

Tags: aem

Is there a possibility to extend and override the html code for the guideContainer in a custom template in adaptive forms for AEM?

I have copied the `guideContainer` under `/libs/fd/af/components/guideContainer` but this isn't working at all if i modify the copied `guideContainer`.